# Change Navigation bar title index colour with Color Set in Assets

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, uinavigationbarappearance

I have to change the last 5 letters of the navigation bar title to be as a color inside my assets.

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            
            .navigationBarTitle("HelloWorld")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        // UIColor.red should be Color("orange1") and only for the last 5 letters (World)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I did it was to add the root view into ZStack with top alignment and add a custom center view after root view. Then I just placed the Texts in a HStack and got the prefix and suffix of the title that you want and change the colors to whichever you'd like. There were different ways to go about this but this is how i chose to do it for this example. The end result looked like this.

```
var navBarTitle: String = "HelloWorld"
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top){
        //Root view with empty Title
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, World")
                .navigationBarTitle("",displayMode: .inline)
        }
        
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text(navBarTitle.prefix(5))
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text(navBarTitle.suffix(5))
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for but hopefully it helps a bit!

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem but I hope it might be helpful for someone who's working with only inline displaymode. For my specific case I was looking for an easy way to change the appearence of navigationbar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color the last five letters of a string in a custom color, you could use this approach:

```
string.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: Color("orange1"), range: NSMakeRange(string.length-5, 5))
```

I'm not sure how you can use this with `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes` syntax, but maybe this helps you anyways

Comment: That's the problem, in a normal string I can do that but I don't know how to do it in UINavigationBar